# Visual Studio code can't install the Go tools

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I try to use VS Code (v1.38.1) via **WSL** and when I launch any go tools installation or command Go:Install/Update tools, I have an issue with permissions. I tried to reinstall WSL and VS Code and got the same result. Manual input `go get -v github.com/mdempsky/gocode` via embedded terminal works correct.

VS Code output console shows this:

```
Installing 2 tools at /home/username/go/bin
  gocode
  gopkgs

Installing github.com/mdempsky/gocode FAILED
Installing github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/cmd/gopkgs FAILED

2 tools failed to install.

gocode:
Error: Command failed: /usr/local/go/bin/go get -v github.com/mdempsky/gocode
go: finding github.com/mdempsky/gocode latest
go: extracting github.com/mdempsky/gocode v0.0.0-20190203001940-7fb65232883f
go get github.com/mdempsky/gocode: rename /home/username/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mdempsky/gocode@v0.0.0-20190203001940-7fb65232883f.tmp-492884992 /home/username/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mdempsky/gocode@v0.0.0-20190203001940-7fb65232883f: permission denied
go: finding github.com/mdempsky/gocode latest
go: extracting github.com/mdempsky/gocode v0.0.0-20190203001940-7fb65232883f
go get github.com/mdempsky/gocode: rename /home/username/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mdempsky/gocode@v0.0.0-20190203001940-7fb65232883f.tmp-492884992 /home/username/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mdempsky/gocode@v0.0.0-20190203001940-7fb65232883f: permission denied

gopkgs:
Error: Command failed: /usr/local/go/bin/go get -v github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/cmd/gopkgs
go: extracting github.com/uudashr/gopkgs v2.0.1+incompatible
go get github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/cmd/gopkgs: rename /home/username/go/pkg/mod/github.com/uudashr/gopkgs@v2.0.1+incompatible.tmp-058746657 /home/username/go/pkg/mod/github.com/uudashr/gopkgs@v2.0.1+incompatible: permission denied
go: extracting github.com/uudashr/gopkgs v2.0.1+incompatible
go get github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/cmd/gopkgs: rename /home/username/go/pkg/mod/github.com/uudashr/gopkgs@v2.0.1+incompatible.tmp-058746657 /home/username/go/pkg/mod/github.com/uudashr/gopkgs@v2.0.1+incompatible: permission denied
```

Here is my `go env` output:

```
username@PC_username:~$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOCACHE="/home/username/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/username/.config/go/env"
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/username/GoProjects"
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build120415101=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Anybody has any idea what may be the issue?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, except `go get -v` doesn't work for me either. VS Code 1.39.2, Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL 1 / Windows 10, go-1.13 from the longsleep backport.
`$ go get -v github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
go: extracting golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20191008105621-543471e840be
build github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv: cannot load golang.org/x/sys/unix: rename /home/ktri/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20191008105621-543471e840be.tmp-968345340 /home/ktri/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20191008105621-543471e840be: permission denied`

Comment: It looks like it is related to permissions - if I do an `ls -la` in `$GOROOT/go/pkg/mod` the problematic packages are marked 500, i.e. read-only. Weirdly enough some packages install fine.

Comment: Just tried wiping my go installation, installed the official binary from golang.org and ran `go get` from bash. Same error, so seems unrelated to VS Code. Possibly caused by WSL running on NTFS screwing up file permissions.

Comment: Now I tried with the Windows version of Go and I'm seeing the same issue. Some packages can't install from VS Code, and some packages won't install at all. I'm beginning to think it's something else. Do you have any kind of antivirus installed? I'm forced to run McAfee here.

Comment: Just tried to reproduce the issue and found out that it's gone. All packages install correctly through "Go: Install/Update tools" as well as bash go get -v. I totally confused! Before that, I had reinstalled Win10 about a week ago. Maybe it was the reason.

Answer (score 3):

That's a known problem with the WSL file system implementation ([Microsoft/WSL#3395, Microsoft/WSL#1956](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3395)) caused by the file watcher active by VSCode. The issue will only be fixed in WSL 2.

As a workaround, you can just exclude folders pkg and bin from Workspace.
[More info](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_i-see-eaccess-permission-denied-error-trying-to-rename-a-folder-in-the-open-workspace) from the official page.